# Unable to use self signed certificates with tokio-rustls

Tags: ssl, rust, tls1.2, rust-tokio

I'm trying to get the examples under https://github.com/quininer/tokio-rustls/tree/master/examples working. I am using self signed key/cert, generated using the openssl tool.

But the handshake fails with a webpki error: `Error: Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: WebPKIError(CAUsedAsEndEntity) }`. Found this related thread: https://github.com/briansmith/webpki/issues/114, but could not tell the current status of this issue

We probably need to live with self signed certs for some time. Is there any workaround, or any other options here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to report this as a bug on github?

Comment: I ended up going with openssl instead. Mostly because I had some other blocker issues(like 25519 support)/questions around rustls, and it was hard to get answers

Comment: Can you turn that into a reply so the question can be closed?

Answer (score 1):

You probably used a CA certificate as a client certificate.

Create a CA:

```
openssl req -x509 -noenc -subj '/CN=example.com' -newkey rsa -keyout root.key -out root.crt
```

Create a certificate signing request (CSR):

```
openssl req -noenc -newkey rsa -keyout client.key -out client.csr -subj '/CN=example.com' -addext subjectAltName=DNS:example.com
```

Sign it using your CA:

```
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA root.crt -CAkey root.key -days 365 -out client.crt -copy_extensions copy
```

And then you use the certificate `client.crt` and the key `client.key`. And the client should trust your `root.crt`.

The `addext` and `copy_extensions` flag ensure that they generated key is `X509v3`, otherwise webpki will start complaining. And `subjectAltName` is required to prevent rustls from complaining.